# How to find record times between two time spans

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

TimeOfDay is timespan. start_time, end_time is also timespan.  How do i find records between start_time and end_time

```
exam.tbl_time_slot.Where(t => !t.deleted && dTime.TimeOfDay <= t.start_time && dTime.TimeOfDay >= t.end_time).ToList()
```

Comment: Currently you're asking: "find records earlier than (or on the dot) 5pm and later than (or on the dot) 8pm", which I don't think is possible for any one record :)

Comment: I have tried everything, is there any solution to that. Plz

Comment: reverse <  : dTime.TimeOfDay >= t.start_time && dTime.TimeOfDay <= t.end_time

Comment: Are you sure `start_time` is a `TimeSpan` and not a `DateTime`? It seems a bit strange, if not impossible to compare `4th july 2018 at 10:14 in the morning` with `Time period of 2 minutes 8 seconds`

Comment: Oops!! actually the db is same across the network and someone have changed the data, while i was debugging. @JordiJordi Yes it should be this. I was giving hit and trial so that's why i posted the wrong code. Thanks

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse db developer is using time datatype of sql server. Which when i import via entity framework by db first approach, it becomes TimeSpan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues

First, as pointed by @Mojtaba your check is wrong. t.start_time should be less than TimeOfDay

```
exam.tbl_time_slot.Where(t => !t.deleted && dTime.TimeOfDay >= t.start_time && dTime.TimeOfDay <= t.end_time).ToList()
```

Second, you will have to ensure that Days value in TimeOfDay, start_time and end_time are 0. Otherwise comparison will give wrong result.

Please check other properties as well in case it does not work

Comment: Friend TimeOfDay, start_time, end_time, as i told you that all are time span. So there is no question of days value. That should be zero.

Comment: @karman: Days is a property of TimeSpan object. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/timespan-in-c-sharp. If the value of this property is different then comparison will be wrong. I also recommend you to use compare method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

```
exam.tbl_time_slot.Where(t => !t.deleted && dTime.TimeOfDay >= t.start_time && dTime.TimeOfDay <= t.end_time).ToList()
```